# How to get the required rows from a table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want all product_id's  having website_id = 0(Zero) and not having other value. Following is my table data,

```
+------------+------------+
| product_id | website_id |
+------------+------------+
|      19112 |          0 |
|      19112 |          1 |
|      19112 |          2 |
|      19113 |          1 |
|      19110 |          0 |
|      19110 |          2 |
|      19114 |          0 |
|      19115 |          0 |
|      19115 |          1 |
|      19116 |          0 |
+------------+------------+
```

I want following rows from above table data;

```
+------------+------------+
| product_id | website_id |
+------------+------------+
|      19114 |          0 |
|      19116 |          0 |
+------------+------------+
```

Can any one help me with query. Thank you!.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the desired result you can use following query

```
select product_id,website_id
from t
group by product_id
having count(*)=sum(website_id = 0)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/644a00/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_id,website_id
from table_name
group by product_id
having sum(website_id) < 1
```

More Simplified version.